# Uncrustify code formatter removes space in C++ one-liner

Tags: c++, code-formatting, uncrustify

How to prevent Uncrustify code formatter from keeping one space in C++ one-liner between `{` and the rest code?

So, it changes this code

```
const Foo &GetBar() const { return bar; }
```

to this

```
const Foo &GetBar() const {return bar; }
```

I search for `return` in default uncrustify config, but found nothing in common with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this has more to do with brace spacing than with the `return`, so I'd check the space settings for braces. The first option I would try to play with would be `sp_inside_braces` (should be "ignore" by default).